# orbit slider overlaps slides - javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I'm using orbit slider in one of my sites and I encountered this issue:
If you click on another slide you want to see (click on the dots under the slides) before the last slide finished it's entering animation, the slides overlaps in such a way that the last slide remains on screen and nevers moves.

You can see it live in this site:

http://www.paintinglulu.com/press-coverage.html

Here is the ScreenShot:

[image]

How can I disable choosing another slide before the last one finished it's animation? Or is there another solution?

Thanks

Comment: Everything working fine here.

Comment: you need to click realy fast on another dot  before the last slides animation ends. i tried to upload a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation :-(

Comment: Post screenshot link here

Comment: here's the screenshot, thanks for trying ketan: http://s23.postimg.org/y2a598ycb/Screenshot_2015_05_01_09_43_22.png

Comment: I check sing that way but didn't get issue like in screenshot. Which browser you are using?

Comment: I can reproduce this in Firefox 37.0.2. When you click on a dot at exactly the same time that another slide would be selected one of those slides gets stuck.

Comment: I'm using chrome 42. Thanks Xufox

Comment: I "solved" this problem by changing to slick slider, works great